# Recursive Function into Non-Recursive Function?

Tags: recursion, groovy

I have the following recursive Grails function:

```
private boolean isCyclic(TreeNode node) {
    boolean cyclic = false
    def myParents = this.parents

    // if there are parents of this node
    if (myParents.size() != 0) {

        // if the new node is in the parents set of this node
        if (myParents.contains(node)) {
            cyclic = true
            return cyclic
        }
        else {
            // go into each parent of this node and test if new node is contained in their parents
            myParents.each { parent ->
                log.debug "go to parent: "+parent.name
                if (cyclic) {
                    return cyclic
                }
                cyclic = parent.isCyclic(node)
            }
        }
    }

    return cyclic
}
```

**How can I transform this function into a non-recursive function?**

Comment: What is that doing?  Looking to see if a node is contained in the parents of a tree node?  Not sure how that gets you cyclic... isn't that just a recursive `contains` method?

Comment: @tim_yates This method checks if adding the TreeNode node would lead to a cycle und the parent to child relation.

Comment: @tim_yates what do you mean by recursive contains?

Comment: @tim_yates where is you answer? It is gone?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if it was what you were looking for. I've added it back so you can verify

Answer (score 2):

I *think* your code above is a `contains` method, rather than a cyclic check...

However here's a quick example of both a contains method and a cyclic check in an iterative style...  Fingers crossed they're right

```
def contains( TreeNode node ) {
    // if this node is the one we're looking for, return true
    if( node == this ) {
        return true
    }
    // A queue of nodes to work on
    def parentQueue = this.parents as Queue

    // A set of nodes we've seen (to avoid loops)
    def seen = [ this ] as Set

    // While we have nodes to look for
    while( parentQueue ) {
        // get the next node
        def next = parentQueue.pop()

        // Check if it's the one we're looking for
        if( next == node ) return true

        // And if not, add it's parents to the queue
        // assuming we've not seen it before
        if( !seen.contains( next ) ) {
            next.parents.each { parentQueue.offer( it ) }
        }
    }
    // Not found
    return false
}

def isCyclic() {
    // A queue of nodes to work on
    def parentQueue = this.parents as Queue

    // A set of nodes we've seen (to detect loops)
    def seen = [ this ] as Set

    // While we have nodes to look for
    while( parentQueue ) {
        // Look at the next element in the queue
        def next = parentQueue.pop()

        // If we've seen it before, it's cyclic
        if( seen.contains( next ) ) return true

        // Otherwise, record we've seen this node
        seen << next

        // And add its parents tothe queue
        next.parents.each { parentQueue.offer( it ) }
    }
    // All done, not cyclic
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically to transform a recursive function into an iterative function you should notice which is the case base(this case is the stop case of recursive function), put all functionality into a loop and use that base case as exit condition of used loop.

Perhaps i didn't explain it very well but every recursive function has an iterative function.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Moertel wrote solution for this problem on his blog.

He clearly explained the transformation of recursive function into the iterative ([link](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html)).

I have used his approach to transform my own functions when I needed and I was convinced that is  correct.
I hope that helps.